# WCCOA Siemens, Referencepoint

Tags: xml, siemens

I hava a pnlfile(XMLdata) from WCCOA Siemens. In the Panel from WCCOA the reference points are different from the pnl file. It seems that when you save it the points,sizes get other values.

So the problem is I can't calculate my way back to the same numbers from mine pnl file to the original values in the panel from WCCOA Siemens.

The Reference point in WCCOA is [53,75] and the Size [51,65] where in the pnl file the reference point = [385,122] and the size [-399,-128]

Does anyone know if there is formula or something that can help get the original values?[Panel with reference point of KLIKFRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24bdQ.png) .

I have many more shapes so there must be something that i can do to do all the refencepoint automatically. I also compared it with other shapes but there seems to be no correlation.

```
    <prop name="RefPoint">385 122</prop>
    <prop name="Enable">True</prop>
    <prop name="Visible">True</prop>
    <prop name="ForeColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="BackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="HoverForeCol">BNO_Wit</prop>
    <prop name="TabOrder">7</prop>
    <prop name="ToolTipText">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8"></prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="layoutAlignment">AlignNone</prop>
    <prop name="snapMode">Point</prop>
    <prop name="DashBackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="AntiAliased">False</prop>
    <prop name="LineType">[solid,oneColor,JoinBevel,CapProjecting,1]</prop>
    <prop name="BorderZoomable">False</prop>
    <prop name="FillType">[solid]</prop>
    <prop name="Geometry">0.1256281407035175 0 0 0.5039370078740157 4.633165829145731 13.51968503937009</prop>
    <prop name="BorderStyle">Normal</prop>
    <prop name="Location">385 122</prop>
    <prop name="Size">-399 -128</prop>
    <prop name="CornerRadius">0</prop>
    <prop name="Transformable">True</prop>
   </properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically in storing the Siemens Panels in XML there is a formula that can be derived by moving the panels and looking what changes in xml. That changes or each shape you have. So you have to derive a formula to solve the changing of paramters